What was the City Gate of Proverbs 31 like?
Proverbs 31 discusses the characteristic traits of a noble wife. Verse 23 reads:

Her husband is respected at the city gate,where he takes his seat among the elders of the land.

Verse 31 goes on to say that the lady will also gain praise at the city gate.
As per OT instructions, city gate was also the place where punishments were carried   out ( Deut 17:5)
Could someone give a description of the city gate including the structure and seating arrangement,
where important decisions were taken/ executed  and household matters discussed in public ?

Using this as a reference:

Defensive: The gate was the primary entry point and was
fortified with wooden doors and sometimes observation towers.

Judges 16:3 ESV

But Samson lay till midnight, and at midnight he arose and took hold
of the doors of the gate of the city and the two posts, and pulled
them up, bar and all, and put them on his shoulders and carried them
to the top of the hill that is in front of Hebron.


Guard rooms: “cells” were used by guards for rest and storage.

Ezekiel 40:10 NASB

The guardrooms of the gate toward the east numbered three on each
side; the three of them had the same measurement. The side pillars
also had the same measurement on each side.


The gate area was an open space used for:

City elders gathered here for important judgments and
decisions.



Genesis 23:10 ESV

Now Ephron was sitting among the Hittites, and Ephron the Hittite
answered Abraham in the hearing of the Hittites, of all who went in at
the gate of his city,




Punishments were carried out in this highly visible area.
It was a bustling hub for trading and markets.
Ritual activities and worship took place at the gate.



Psalm 24:7 ESV

Lift up your heads, O gates!
And be lifted up, O ancient doors,
that the King of glory may come in.


Infrastructure: The gates featured drainage canals due to their low
topographical position, aiding in effective water management.


Another good example is Ruth ch4 vv1-2, where Boaz easily finds the man he wants to do business with, among the passers-by, and has no difficulty in laying his hands on ten elders to act as witnesses. So "open-air old people's community centre" can perhaps be added to the list.

We would need to know the city in question to describe it in detail and even then biblical data is sparse. A problem here is that the city is unknown It is probably not Jerusalem, because this is not a proverb attributed to Solomon but to another king, Lemuel of Massa. That said, the biblical description and function of the city gate varied, according to time and place. One of the clearest descriptions of the cultural function of the city's gate area is found in the story of Ruth.
Ruth 4

1 Boaz went to the gate and took a seat there. Along came the other
redeemer of whom he had spoken. Boaz called to him by name, “Come, sit
here.” And he did so. 2 Then Boaz picked out ten of the elders of the
town and asked them to sit nearby... 9 Boaz then said to the elders
and to all the people, “You are witnesses today that I have acquired
from Naomi all the holdings of Elimelech, Chilion and Mahlon. 10 I
also acquire Ruth the Moabite, the widow of Mahlon, as my wife, in
order to raise up a family for her late husband on his estate, so that
the name of the deceased may not perish from his people and his place.
Do you witness this today?” 11 All those at the gate, including the
elders, said, “We do..."

This describes the situation at Bethlehem in the time of the judges. If we think of Jerusalem in the time of Jesus, business such of this would have been handled inside the city at the meeting place of the Sanhedrin. Smaller cities had their own rabbinical courts, so the city gate would be mainly a place of commerce, news and gossip. Other biblical data about city gates can be found in this articlefrom the Jewish Encyclopedia:

The gate and the adjoining open area constituted the market-place
(Neh. viii. 16, xiii. 19; Job xxix. 7; II Kings vii. 1); hence such
names as "fish-gate," "sheep-gate" (Neh. iii. 1, 3, 32; xii. 39; Zeph.
i. 10). The gates offered the main opportunity for social intercourse.
The wells were sometimes situated here (II Sam. xxiii. 15-16). Here
news from the outside was sure to be announced first (I Sam. iv. 18);
private grief or public calamity found "at the gate" ready
sympathizers among the assembled throng of idlers (comp. II Macc. iii.
19; Gen. xix. 1; Ps. lxix. 12 [A. V. 13]; Prov. xxxi. 31); matters of
public concern were discussed (I Kings xxii. 10; Jer. xxxviii. 7....),
public announcements were made (Jer. xvii. 19 et seq.; Prov. i. 21,
viii. 3), and court and council sessions were held here (Job xxix. 7,
xxxi. 21; Prov. xxxi. 23; Lam. v. 14; Deut. xvi. 18, xxi. 19 et seq.,
xxii. 15-16; Josh. xx. 4).


Archaeologists have uncovered several city-gate areas from the time of the kings. These include Hazor, Megiddo, and Gezer. The location and size of King Lemuel's city is unknown.
As far as the specific reference mentioned in the OP goes, the lady in question is involved in commerce at the gate and her husband sits there among the town elders.

She makes her own coverlets;
fine linen and purple are her clothing. 23 Her husband is prominent at the city gates
as he sits with the elders of the land. 24 She makes garments and sells them,
and stocks the merchants with belts. 25 She is clothed with strength and dignity,
and laughs at the days to come. 26 She opens her mouth in wisdom;
kindly instruction is on her tongue. 27 She watches over the affairs of her household,
and does not eat the bread of idleness.

This is clearly the gate of a major city. We cannot identify it with Jerusalem, however, because this is not an Israelite king. Rather it is King Lemuel of Massa, about whom there is much speculation. These gates must have been larger and busier that those of the Bethlehem in the time of Ruth, but probably not as busy as the gate-area of Jerusalem in the Golden Age of Solomon when throngs must have assembled to get glimpses of kings and queens arriving whither their retinues.  (1 Kings 5:14)
